# Minimizing étale fundamental group in a given function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field. Consider the profinite groups arising as étale fundamental groups of irreducible normal schemes with function field $K$.

Is there one profinite group among them that they all surject to?

Comment: Welcome Smough. The answer seems to be negative. Take $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ and consider the etale fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}\setminus S$ with $S$ a finite closed set. As $S$ gets larger, so does the fundamental group. Also,  every irreducible normal scheme with function field $K$ can be realized as $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus S$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar In this case, they all surject to the fundamental group of $\mathbb A^1$ (or $\mathbb P^1$).

Comment: For a curve, the answer is positive - the unique proper normal model does the trick. For the function field of a smooth proper surface, the answer is probably positive in a silly way - take a generic hyperplane section $C \subset S$, whose fundamental group surjects to the fundamental group of the surface, and then blow up a bunch of points on $C$ so you can contract $C$, killing its fundamental group.

Comment: @WillSawin You're right. Somehow I misread the question.